# Conceptual Understanding of Reference Frames correct?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, reference-frames, rotational-kinematics

The problem is as follows:

> A cart has a velocity to the right. There is a wheel on the cart (fastened to it). Determine the angular speed of the wheel so that the velocity at a point on the top of the rim is equal to zero.

I solved the problem and found a positive angular velocity in the z direction. However, I do not understand this. As far as I can tell, since there is angular velocity, there has to be a tangential velocity as well. Even for an external observer, I cannot understand that the tangential velocity is 0. Where is my understanding failing me here?

Comment: Which axis is the wheel's axis of rotation? By definition, the angular velocity vector is supposed to point along the axis of rotation, not in the physical direction a point on the rim of the wheel is moving at any given instant (its tangential velocity).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple example of this is a wheel that rolls without slipping. I'll try to make the example as illustrative as I can.

Imagine you're stuck to the side of a giant runaway wheel that is rolling without slipping along the ground. In this scenario, right as the wheel touches the ground you're not moving. This is just the condition for a wheel to be considered rolling without slipping. If you had a friend on the ground, right at the instant you hit the ground you could get a good look at their face. Your friend would see you as stationary(if only for a second) and you see your friend as stationary. The ground is the external reference frame, and so you have zero velocity relative to the external frame.

Soon after that the trajectory of the wheel will lift you upwards. In the top half of the circle you get flung forward at incredible speed and the world seems like a blur. But once again as you near the ground, because the wheel is rolling without slipping, you appear to 'stop' relative to the ground.

If the wheel is rolling at speed $V$ to the right, we can just as easily mount the wheel on a cart rolling right at speed $V$ and spin it at whatever angular velocity it would need to roll without slipping. This will create the same condition that at one point on the wheel the tangential velocity is always zero.

If you've ever been to an amusement park ride like the teacups you may have kind of felt this 'temporary stop'. As the whole ride spins and your individual carts spin, there are times when all of a sudden it feels like you stop and are able to get a clear look at your surroundings. This temporary stop is inevitably always followed by an equally strong lurch.

Comment: Also this completely slipped my mind when writing, but this type of path taken by a particle on a wheel is called a [cycloid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycloid). There's a great animation that may help.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write this, beautiful explanation!

Answer (score 0):

A general planar body that translates on its center of mass *and* rotates is going to have some point (either on the body, or somewhere in space) with zero linear velocity. This is called the instant center of rotation as the body can be said that it instantaneously rotates about this point.

If the center of rotation happens to be on a contact point then it is said that the body is purely "rolling" on the contact. If the point is at a distance from the contact, then the body will have tangential velocity on the contact, and thus it is said to be "slipping".